# A second button to start php script, how?

Tags: php, jquery

I have read the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697484/a-button-to-start-php-script-how/), to execute PHP scripts with the click of a button.  But what if I have a "*nested button*", like this :

```
    <?php
    if(!empty($_POST['act'])) {
        echo "Ready to rock!";
        $someVar = "Rock n Roll";
        if(!empty($_POST['act2'])) {
            echo $someVar;
        } else {
    ?>
        <form method="POST" action="">
            <input type="hidden" name="act2" value="run">
            <input type="submit" value="Rock It!">
        </form>
    <?php
        }
    } else {
    ?>
    <form method="POST" action="">
        <input type="hidden" name="act" value="run">
        <input type="submit" value="Show It!">
    </form>
    <?php } ?>
```

I heard my problem can be solved with jQuery, but I no idea.

anyone please.

Answer (score 0):

To execute a script on the server you use the action property of your form:

```
<form method="POST" action="myscript.php">
```

When clicking a `input type="submit"` the browser will go to to action of the form surrounding the `input type="submit"`

Nesting is not a issue, as the browser always will look for the *'surrounding' form*.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in second form, so it will never calls in this code, because it fails in first $_POST variable IF statement, because in second form you do not POST variable "act". so you need to add it

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    <input type="hidden" name="act" value="run">
    <input type="hidden" name="act2" value="run">
    <input type="submit" value="Rock It!">
</form>
```

with this form you should see `echo $someVar;`

p.s. if form action property is emtpy, by default it submits form to the same php script

Answer (score 0):

Just like @DTukans said here, you need the hidden field. If you would post the second form, the value of act will be lost if you are not having a hidden field with the value of act from the first form.

In php you can also check which submit button you submitted by giving the `input[type="submit"]` a name, such as `<input type="submit" name="form2">`, then you could check if you submitted that form by:
`if (isset($_POST['form2'])) {}`, but this is not the case here.

Use the hidden input and you will be good to go.