# Launch Wordpress Site from index

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to launch a wordpress website from a non wordpress static home page (index.html) using a button.

The index.html will provide users an option to leave me their email contact info or redirect them to the wordpress site I have created when they click the "Enter" button.

The wordpress site works fine when the standard wordpress index.php file is located in the site root.  When I replace this file with my own index.html file (with the button and contact code), I can't get the wordpress index.php file to launch.  I renamed the original wordpress index.php to indexWP.php and I call that file from my new index.html file using the code suggestion here:  [A button to start php script, how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697484/a-button-to-start-php-script-how)

```
<form action="indexwp.php" method="get">
  <input type="submit" value="Enter">
</form>
```

When I use the above, it gives me a 404 Page Not Found error when I click Enter.

The original Wordpress index.php looks like this (renamed to indexwp.php):

```
<?php
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require('./wp-blog-header.php');
```

I'm a noob so I suspect it's something I'm misinterpreting with the above sample code.

Comment: I would rather hit myself on the head really hard with my own severed arm than use a page with an unneeded "enter" page... If something, that kills user experience.

Comment: Create a page in WordPress and assign it as front page. Or just create `home.php` and customize that; done. Check here  for more info http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

Comment: The Enter is used to get into the Wordpress site because it's password protected while under construction.  The index.html is meant to be a separate and simple page independent of wordpress so I don't have to deal with header/nav/footer suppression within wordpress for the temporary home page.

Comment: Totally agree with @elclanrs, why go to such lengths when you can solve this fast and easy with a theme template file?

Comment: Why not just password protect the site using basic authentication while the site is in development? No changes would be needed to the code at all, just to the web server configuration. When ready to go live you just turn off the basic authentication.

Comment: I'm using a Yootheme template, it's not obvious to me how to create a non password protected temporary home page with no header/footer/navigation (simple blank page) while still password protecting the actual under construction site in its entirety.  I don't want to show the Yootheme template design on the temporary home page.

Comment: As soon as you create an empty `home.php` or `front-page.php` you'll get a blank page. You don't need to include the header and footer, just use what you need. My advice when you work with WordPress is to do everything you can "the WordPress way", and that's 90% of the time, and your case is pretty common; no exception. In Settings->Reading you can set custom pages as home pages.

Comment: The temp homepage has the following requirements:I want the option to collect user names interested in seeing the site - a notification list.  The temp homepage is meant to allow users to leave their emails for those that wish to be notified when we launch.  The temp homepage also gives certain users an opportunity to Enter if they have the correct PW.  The password protection option offered in Wordpress is good and protects the entire site.  My code to allow users to submit their email address is working and I didn't include it in the above example.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following in your .htaccess (Below the Wordpress definitions)

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

Index.html is your page and index.php is that of Wordpress.

But Wordpress uses the domain-name without index.php for it's home page so you keep getting thrown into your index.html (logon page). You would need to automatically redirect to index.php if a cookie is set (or something).

Better would be installing Wordpress in a subdirectory if you really want an enter page like this. Then you could have /index.html redirected to /WP/index.php.

Check [this article](http://blog.boulderdigitalarts.com/2010/10/developing-wordpress-in-a-subdirectory-and-then-redirecting-to-the-root-directory/) (and its links) for developing Wordpress in a subdirectory.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you are using apache2 web server, maybe .htaccess could help or is causing a problem.

how about: `DirectoryIndex index.php` rule. here apache2 will use index.php as directory listing and user can now go to exapmle.com/index.html.

better still why not create a home.php file, add you index.html code to it, then reference home.php like example.com/home using htaccess to remove the '.php' extension like: 
`RewriteRule ^home$ $1.php`

as never nother with the static index.html.

Good Luck :)